# sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" in angular

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-security, role-based

I am implementing [Role based spring security](https://www.javaguides.net/2018/09/spring-boot-spring-mvc-role-based-spring-security-jpa-thymeleaf-mysql-tutorial.html)

In this example they have used thymeleaf for frontend purpose, but I am using angular9 with html.

they are using `sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"` to provide access to the admin,in the same way if I want to provide the same thing in html, for that I have used the following code,

```
    <li *ngFor="let user of users">
        {{user.username}} ({{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}})
        - <a sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" (click)="deleteUser(user.userid)" class="text-danger">Delete</a>
    </li>
```

The person logged in is Role_user, eventhough the delete link is visible to the user.
How can I restrict.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `sec:authorize` is a thymeleaf specific implementation. Angular has no idea about this.

Comment: You will have to do that by yourself probably by having a roles field in the response of an ajax call and then by checking if the the particular role is present for the user.

Answer (score 1):

use *ngIf **directive** to **show and hide the anchor tag**

```
<li *ngFor="let user of users">
        {{user.username}} ({{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}})
        - <a *ngIf="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" (click)="deleteUser(user.userid)" class="text-danger">Delete</a>
    </li>
```

but the **hasRole()** must return **boolean**. because ***ngIf** accepts the **boolean**